# Check if there is always the same value in the row of an array for each row C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

I am looking for an algorithm or a code able to browse a 2D array (a matrix) and check if we have differents values for each rows or not.
If the values are differents we return 1 else 0

an example is better:

```
    0   1   2   3
0       2
1           2   4
2               6
3   1
```

in the case 0;2 we have the value 2
in the case 2;3 we have the value 6

In this example for the line 1 we have 2 values (in 1;2 and 1;3) : 2 and 4.
2 and 4 are not equal, we can exit the loop and return 1

```
    0   1   2   3
0       2   2
1           1   1
2               6
3   4
```

In this other example, in the first line all the values are equals to 2 so we go into the second line, all the values are equals to 1, we go into the third line, all the values equals 6, and the last line, all the values equal 4 so we return 0

I don't really know in what way I can do that

Thanks in advance for your helps

Best regards

Comment: But have you even tried? You are very unlikely to find help if you don't seem to have put any effort in solving the problem yourself

Comment: Is the matrix a native array? A one-dimensional array (all the elements are arranged linearly in memory, but accessed using two coordinates) or an array of arrays? Are the missing elements 0 and just ignored? Or, in case it's not a native array, is it a custom-made sparse matrix implementation? Rows-first or columns-first?

Comment: Why are there empty cells?

Comment: I don't have enough logic to do that

Comment: this is a custom 2D array

Comment: The emply cells are worth 0

Comment: So you mean valid cells will not have 0 right?

Comment: By default all the values in the matrix are set to 0

Comment: If a cells worth 0 I don't display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this which has a time complexity of O(N*M) solution

```
    //N = Number of rows
    //M = Number of cols
    //arr is the 2D array

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int curr = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != 0) {
                if (curr == 0) {
                    curr = arr[i][j];
                } else if (arr[i][j] != curr) {
                    //This row has different values
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; //All rows have the same value
```

Comment: I don't understand why you initialize the current at 0

Comment: If a row has `0 0 0 0 0 2  3`, then curr will be 0 until it hits 2, after that, since 2!=3, this row will return 1

Comment: I have updated my answer, there was indeed a bug. Let me know if this is still confusing or not working